# Can access the .text attribute of a label but not set it

Tags: ios, swift

In my viewController I have a label which I've created an outlet for. I'd like to set the text for this label programmatically using a static text (in this case just a simple Hello World".) I can access the attribute .text, but can't set it. I'm using Swift4 but from the docs that shouldn't be an issue.

I'm also using a PageView to navigate through my controllers and this one is the second view.

Any ideas why?

```
class myViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(self.myLabel.text!) // Prints correctly
        self.myLabel.text = "hello world" // Doesn't set
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show constraints ??

Comment: @Sh_Khan yup I made it to narrow hahahaha. This is what happens when your sleep deprived.  Thanks!